# What happens if I don't kill Neo Undyne and kill normal Undyne?

Tags: undertale

I forgot to kill Gerson and Undyne was normal, did that abort the genocide run?

Comment: You can't kill Gerson, so that's not the problem. Can you clarify exactly what happened? Did you deplete the kill counter in Waterfall? Did you attack Monster Kid?

Comment: basically instead of me getting into a fight he slipped and i didn't save him wat does that mean. but i found out i had to restart

Answer (score 5):

The most likely problem is that you failed to deplete the kill counter in Waterfall. From your comments, you indicate that you saw the Neutral version of the Monster Kid bridge cutscene. This cutscene plays out differently if you're on the Genocide route, so there are only two possibilities:

- You failed to deplete the kill counter in Waterfall (which causes the Genocide run to abort when you get to the bridge).
- You aborted the Genocide run before reaching Monster Kid, most likely by failing to kill one of the unique monsters on [this list](https://undertale.fandom.com/wiki/Genocide_Route#Requirements). The only ones in Waterfall are Glad Dummy (who replaces Mad Dummy) and Shyren. If you did not encounter Glad Dummy, then you had already aborted the run at some point before that.

Comment: i restarted my run and i fixed it